# Student-group allocation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matching

I have 150 students, and have to assign them to specific groups (with different topics). They can rank their preferences for the topics and will each have different groups. My main issue (more than being optimal with respect to a certain metric) is that the outcome has to be doable in the timetable.

More precisely, here are some data:

- 150 students
- 10 topics that each student will rank
- each student will be assigned to 5 topics
- the groups for each topic have to be between 10 and 15 (there may be various groups for the same topic or no group for some topics)
- the final assignment has to fit into a timetable: there will be only 5 time slots (different groups can be on the same slots, but students cannot duplicate themselves to follow various groups at the same time)

What kind of algorithms could provide possibilities for such a situation?

Comment: Just commenting because i'm interested in the answer for your problem :)
Quick question : is there some rules on how the subject have to be chosen for the students ?

Comment: @MatthiasDec This would require specifying a cost function. In fact I don't need the solution to be that good in this respect, since varying a bit the cost would change many groups. The biggest constraint is probably the timetable-compatibility, and the choices of the students may be used more as a first heusitic before balancing or swapping. It would be nonetheless good if no student gets none of his choices...